# Restart while loop in bash script from last position

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a bash script that will take a file as input, read through each line in the file and perform a task on that line. In the example below, I'm just printing out each line. What I would like to do is keep track of my position in the while loop, so that if something happens (e.g. computer crash), I can restart the script and have it continue the while loop where it left off, rather than restart from the beginning. I am currently printing my progress to a log file (which tracks which line of the file I'm on), and this would be automatically read to get the last completed loop position (0 if there is no log file), but I'm not sure how to get my while loop to begin from this point, rather than start from scratch. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":l:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        l)
            l=${OPTARG} # input file
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ ! -f ./log.txt ]; then
    position=0
    printf "Starting from beginning of file\n";
else
    position=$(head log.txt)
    printf "Starting on line ${position}\n";
fi

while read line; do
    printf "WORKING on line ${line}\n"
    printf "$position\n" > log.txt
    let position=position+1
done < ${l}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can get `read` to seek so the simple solution is to stick a position check at the top of the `while` loop and burn lines you've already seen by continuing instead of doing work.

Alternatively, and likely a good bit cheaper for large log files that you have processed a good portion of the data from, would be to use process substitution instead of the raw file as input and seek into the file with `tail -+$position`.

As @rici points out though you should check that your log file has contents and only the contents that you want rather than using the file blindly as there are any number of ways the file might not be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Etan. A positional check in the while loop does work easily enough. Not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @user3182448: Personally, I'd go for option 2, which is roughly to change the last line from `done < ${1}` to `done < <(tail -n+$position "$1")`. Note that there are lots of race conditions in the creation of the log file, and in at least a percentage of crashes, you will not be able to recover with this strategy because the log file will be empty. (`> log` first truncates the file and then writes to it; if the crash happens after the truncate and before the write is flushed....)

Comment: `printf "$position\n" > tmp-log.txt && mv tmp-log.txt log.txt` mostly fixes the race condition, as `mv` is atomic and guarantees that `log.txt` is either updated or left untouched.

Comment: Great. Thank you all. rici your code makes things much cleaner and I've added what you suggested chepner.